# writing a testfile for a program

Tags: ruby, testing

So with some help of stackoverflowers i has started and published my first Ruby program. It is a simple program which can only started and runned in one way.
Now i would like to write a testing file for the program there: https://github.com/saigkill/youtube_dlhelper.
The relevant files are under lib/ and lib/youtube_dlhelper.
I have read a lot of sites about rspec, cucumber and other testing stuff. But i'm not sure, what in my program can be tested.
Maybe anyone can help me with this?

---

Thank you very much. Now i'm thinking i have understood the basics. 
I have defined different testcases:
* running the script with a url as parameter -> should be passig
* running the script without an parameter -> should fail.

Now i'm interesting in how to extend the test to giving input to that interactive script. After starting the script i'm using that code:

```
def self.check_target
      @entrygroup = ask 'What kind of entry do you have? (Interpret or Group)'

      case
        when @entrygroup == 'Interpret' then
          @firstname = ask 'Whats the first name of your interpret?'
          @surname = ask 'Whats the surname of your interpret?'
          $folder = "#{@surname}_#{@firstname}/Youtube-Music"
        when @entrygroup == 'Group' then
          @group = ask 'Whats the name of the group?'
          $folder = "#{@group}/Youtube-Music"
        else
          puts 'Just the entries "Interpret" or "Group" are allowed'
          abort('Aborted')
          puts 'Breakpoint'
      end
    end
```

How can i tell the test which input to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am new to [TDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development). I write [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com) applications and I use **RSpec** and **Capybara** but command line applications I would try to learn and use **[minitest](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest)** which is part of ruby core now. You can use the gem if you would like to use the latest version.

The code syntax of all testing frameworks is relatively easy to learn. You will understand how it works in 15-20 minutes tops. What you have to understand though is that TDD is a kind of *policy* or *strategy* on how to develop programs.

To sum it up:

- First you write the tests which the **fail**
- Then you write the **code**

and repeat this procedure on and on. Once you become accustomed writing tests, you'll become proficient in writing smarter and smarter tests, i.e. inspecting objects, testing classes, etc. The interesting part here is that if your test become smart enough over time, when and if your new code breaks older parts, you know.

Now far as RSpec is concerned create a `spec/` directory in your project's root path - *you can chose your path but I see no reason to break the convention here* - and add these lines to your `.rspec`

```
--format progress documentation
--color
```

I use `autotest` with RSpec. There is a very nice [web tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/how-to-integrate-rspec-into-a-sinatra-app/) by Jeffrey Way which shows how to use **RSpec** with *autotest*, you might wanna take a look.

PS. For minitest take a look [here](http://rubylearning.com/blog/2011/07/28/how-do-i-test-my-code-with-minitest/).